# .htaccess ssl & non-ssl redirects

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write some simple rules to redirect to https for a couple of urls and redirect to http for others. Below is my current setup but it is causing redirect loops. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(sign-in|register)+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(sign-in|register)+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This first ruleset is redirecting all traffic to HTTPS when the requester has not indicated HTTPS, only when they're trying to reach the `sign-in` or `register` page.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(sign-in|register)+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This second rule is redirecting all traffic to non-SSL when HTTPS is requested and the URL is NOT `sign-in` or `register`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(sign-in|register)+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Both redirects use 301 redirects which are cached by your browser, so if at some point you accidentally redirected to the wrong place, that might be used instead of what you have happening here.

The problem is when you try to visit a page after you're logged in, you'll be redirected right back out of `HTTPS`. So if you're not handling the sign-in request in the sign-in directory, or if you're redirecting them back out of HTTPS.

There could be substantial overlap where anything that's not in the sign-in or register folders bounced back and forth between HTTPS and HTTP.

Comment: The issue I am having is when I try to access /register. I have turned on rewrite logging and it is trying to access https /register over and over again. Based on what I am trying to achieve which is to protect /register and /sign-in and force http on all others - do you know how i should modify my rules?

Comment: FYI - I always post back to the same url when filling out the register or sign in forms

Comment: What directory do they go to once they're logged in? Or do you only use SSL for authentication purposes, then drop them back to HTTP?

Comment: They can access a bunch of different directories once logged in, not /admin/* or /member/* etc, so I need the ability to specify which directories are ssl vs non-ssl