# https htaccess exclude some url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I know this question has been asked a lot, but i try a lot of answers and didnt succeed.
i try those answers:
[.htaccess ssl & non-ssl redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035818/htaccess-ssl-non-ssl-redirects)

[Remove SSL integration from a specific folder using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539114/remove-ssl-integration-from-a-specific-folder-using-htaccess)

and a few others that i find on google.
i only have ssl on 3 pages of the site and i want to make a general rule, that the other pages should be redirect to http when they are on https. im like Jon Snow i know nothing about apache and htaccess.

so this what i try so far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(page1|page2|page3)+ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

and this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page1/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page2/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

the part of send to http works but the exception dont or they send all to http or redirect to the index.

to clarify i didnt put both codes at same time.

other rules on:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com\$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteRule !\.(js|txt|ico|gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|png|PNG|css|swf|pdf|xml|XML|eot|EOT|ttf|TTF|woff|WOFF)$ index.php
```

full url as requested:
https://www.example.com.br/area-restrita/
it can have more information after the 'area-restrita' part

Comment: Provide an example full URL that you want to exclude and is not working for you? Also do you have other rules in this .htaccess?

Comment: I edit the question to put the other rules

Comment: But you didn't provide an example full URL that you want to exclude and is not working for you

Comment: edit again, with the full url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(area-restrita|page2) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com\$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com.br/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule !\.(js|txt|ico|gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|png|PNG|css|swf|pdf|xml|XML|eot|EOT|ttf|TTF|woff|WOFF)$ index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: it still redirects to the http on all pages even the 'area-restrita'

Comment: Open Firebug and visit `https://www.example.com.br/area-restrita/`. Check in Net tab what you get.

Comment: i use the network part of chrome console:
it gives: 302 Found on the the https and later:
200
OK
https://www.example.com.br/area-restrita
Redirect

Comment: but my idea was to NOT redirect those 2 pages, i dont know if a didnt explain right, cause english is not my first language.

I want redirect every URL excpet those 2.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Is there any .htaccess inside `/area-restrita/` also?

Comment: no, its a zend project there is only one htaccess. the 'area-restrita' its not a actual folder, but the zend reads the url and show the right content

Comment: ok what happens when you visit `http://www.example.com.br/area-restrita` does it stay same?

Comment: yes the site works normal if i dont use the https, when i use it redirects to http.
the only odd thing i notice now is that when i put some parameter on the url(after the area-restrita part) it redirects to index.php

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out. This was really tricky due to zend framework.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect the whole site to **https** except for some particular directories / URLs and in these particular cases you still want them served via **http**, you can use this technique in virtual.conf; otherwise when the RewriteCond match, the particular pages will always receive the error **"404 page not found"**

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ServerName www.example.com

  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app1/.*$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app2/.*$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L] 

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=apps.example.com [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app1/.*$ [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app2/.*$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^.*$ http://apps.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,P] 

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ServerName apps.example.com
  DocumentRoot /home/sites/example.com/public_html
</VirtualHost>
```